# Proper data transfer between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have few questions about passing data to another activity. Let's say I have three activities I called them

**first activity**

**second activity**

**third activity**

When app is enabled by user, the user is in the first activity. To go from the first activity to the third activity user must also go through the second activity. The workflow

**first activity (user push button) ->** 
**second activity (user push button) ->** 
**third activity**

Let's assume I need data from the first activity in the third activity, so I need to pass my HashMap with my data from first activity to the second activity and then to the third activity?, is there any way to pass data directly from first activity to third activity but like I said, user has to go also through second activity.

I'm doing this in that way...

```
Intent secondActivity = new Intent(this, secondActivity.class);
secondActivity.putExtra("myHashMap", dataHashMap);
this.startActivity(secondActivity);
```

then in the second activity I have this part of code

```
    secondActivity = getIntent();
    dataHashMap = (HashMap<String, 
    String>)secondActivity.getSerializableExtra("myHashMap");
```

and then I'm repeating this upper two steps for the third activity. Is this correct way? because looks a little bit confusing and time consuming. Also there is another problem, now if I am in the third activity and I want to go back to the second or first activity I have always pass some HashMap because activities expects this type of data. Is there a way to sometimes return to a previous activity but no longer pass any data (HashMap in my case) if it is not needed?.

```
secondActivity.putExtra("myHashMap", dataHashMap); //- I would like to sometimes skip this step
```

I tried to this code below to handle with this but it does not work, my app keep stopping/crashing because second activity expects hashMap data from the third activity.

```
secondActivity = getIntent();
if(secondActivity != null){
     dataHashMap = (HashMap<String, 
     String>)secondActivity.getSerializableExtra("myHashMap");
}
```

Thanks for answers, regards.

Comment: No. unless you store in app pref or db.

Comment: @SouravGanguly I have mysql database so I should add  asynctask class 
to each activity where I want to get some data and download this data from database using asynctask to display if I need some?

Comment: Use EventBus library created by greenrobot

Comment: Are you altering the data in the `HashMap` in third  `Activity` and returning it to second `Activity`?

Comment: @DavidWasser no I just need one element from this HashMap "userName" and it's terrible for me that I can't just get this HashMap directly from first activity to third activity instead I also have to pass HashMap through second activity. Do you have any tips? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable that is placed inside `Application` class instance. This variable is shared for all activities and other elements of the application.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options. Firstly, you said in a comment that you only need one element. In that case you can just pass the one element as an "extra" in the `Intent`, instead of passing the entire `HashMap`.

Secondly, I don't understand why you return from the third `Activity` to the second `Activity` by calling `startActivity()`. You should just call `finish()` and that will return you to the second `Activity`.

If you need to return some data from the third `Activity` to the second `Activity`, you should start third `Activity` using `startActivityForResult()` and set the data to return in third `Activity` using `setResult()` and the data will be returned to second `Activity` in `onActivityResult()`.

Another option is to do it exactly as you have done it, but also copy the `hashMap` into the `Intent` as an "extra" each time you call `startActivity()`. If you only have a handfull of entries in the `hashMap` it won't make any noticeable difference in performance.